# How to export/import modules between component files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, file, charts, chart.js

I have a general question about how pages handle imports. When you import a file into another, are the imported files declarations and imports available in the file your importing it into?

Instead of importing the same component into multiple modules I was advised to import the component in the main module and inherit that component in the other pages I want to use it in. I am not aware of how to do this. When I solely import the main module (as seen below) I still get errors that my import ChartComponent is not defined. How do you import modules into other modules?

I have a page with the following code:

```
main.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MainPage } from './main';
import { MomentModule, TimeAgoPipe } from "angular2-moment";
import { AlertCardComponent } from '../../components/alert-card/alert-card';  
import { AlertCardManageComponent } from '../../components/alert-definition-card/alert-definition-card';  
import { ThingCardComponent } from '../../components/thing-card/thing-card';
import { ThingDetailsPage } from '../thing-details/thing-details';
import { AttributesPage } from "../attributes/attributes";

import { ChartComponent } from '../../components/chartist/chart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainPage,
    AlertCardComponent,
    AlertCardManageComponent,
    ThingCardComponent,
    ChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MainPage),
    MomentModule
  ],

  exports: [AlertCardComponent,AlertCardManageComponent,ThingCardComponent,ThingDetailsPage,AttributesPage]

})
export class MainPageModule { }
```

I want to access the { ChartComponent } import/declaration from this page and have the two following files inherit it:

```
things-details.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ThingDetailsPage } from './thing-details';
import { MomentModule } from "angular2-moment";
import { MainPageModule } from '../main/main.module'; 
// import { ChartComponent } from '../../components/chartist/chart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ThingDetailsPage,
    // ChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ThingDetailsPage),
    MomentModule,
    MainPageModule
  ] 
})
export class ThingDetailsPageModule {}
```

+

```
attributes.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AttributesPage } from "../attributes/attributes";
import { MainPageModule } from '../main/main.module';
import {MomentModule} from "angular2-moment";
// import { ChartComponent } from '../../components/chartist/chart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AttributesPage,
    // ChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AttributesPage),
    MomentModule,
    MainPageModule
  ] 
})
export class AttributePageModule {}
```

As seen above, I am importing MainPageModule into each of my sub files, but I am still not able to access the { ChartComponent } import and declaration from the main.module.ts file.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have lazy module?

Answer (score 1):

All module will be imported to main module.

Try to use into `main.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MainPage),
    MomentModule,
    ThingDetailsPageModule,
    AttributePageModule
],
```

comment the line `MainPageModule` from these files

```
things-details.module.ts
attributes.module.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main module, try adding `ChartComponent` to the list in `exports: [AlertCardComponent,AlertCardManageComponent,ThingCardComponent,ThingDetailsPage,AttributesPage]`.